# Split array into chunks - is there faster method?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance

I'm looking for the quickest method to split an array into chunks of fixed size (last one can be smaller, of course). I've looked throughout the site and didn't find any performance-wise comparisons, so I wrote them, and here are the results:

> Time in microseconds, mean/error/stddev
>
> For `int[]` - 30.02 | 0.1002 | 0.0937
>
> For `IEnumerable<int>` - 76.67 | 0.2146 | 0.1902

**Update**: Version below (in @Markus' answer) is 139.5 | 0.6702 | 0.5597

Most popular here on SO and frequently recommended method to use LINQ's  `GroupBy` with `index/chunkSize` is a no go - 267 microseconds is way too greater than either of aforementioned implementations.

Is there any faster way to split arrays?

P.S.
This is the code for `Array` and `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Splits <paramref name="source"/> into chunks of size not greater than <paramref name="chunkMaxSize"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Array to be split</param>
    /// <param name="chunkMaxSize">Max size of chunk</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> of <see cref="Array"/> of <typeparam name="T"/></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> AsChunks<T>(this T[] source, int chunkMaxSize)
    {
        var pos = 0;
        var sourceLength = source.Length;
        do
        {
            var len = Math.Min(pos + chunkMaxSize, sourceLength) - pos;
            if (len == 0)
            {
                yield break;;
            }
            var arr = new T[len];
            Array.Copy(source, pos, arr, 0, len);
            pos += len;
            yield return arr;
        } while (pos < sourceLength);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splits <paramref name="source"/> into chunks of size not greater than <paramref name="chunkMaxSize"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source"><see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to be split</param>
    /// <param name="chunkMaxSize">Max size of chunk</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> of <see cref="Array"/> of <typeparam name="T"/></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> AsChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkMaxSize)
    {
        var arr = new T[chunkMaxSize];
        var pos = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            arr[pos++] = item;
            if (pos == chunkMaxSize)
            {
                yield return arr;
                arr = new T[chunkMaxSize];
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
        if (pos > 0)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref arr, pos);
            yield return arr;
        }
    }
```

P.P.S Complete solution with BenchmarkDotNet tests is [on GitHub](https://github.com/AlexSeleznyov/SplitToChunk).

Comment: [Why do you care about performance](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)?

Comment: [`Span<T>`](http://adamsitnik.com/Span/) is coming.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, is that a bad thing? If it is fast and easy to achieve - why stuck with slow implementation?

Comment: @mjwills LINQ-based is very slow, and I doubt this one will be faster. Will add to tests and update the question.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Because as we should be solving real world problems before performance problems.  Why are you using C# and worried about performance... degrades to why are you using C++ and worried about performance.. degrades to ... just use Machine Code?

Comment: [Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/).

Comment: @mjwills i'm afraid you've missed the PPS. I don't guess, I test. So the timings can be easily validated. This is way I've shared code, too.

Comment: @mjwills haven't pushed it yet. Give me a sec :)

Comment: Beating a simple array for speed might be the 3rd hardest thing in programming. The upside of IEnumerable<T> is that unlike an array the entire sequence doesn't have to be materlized in memory.

Comment: @Theraot, thanks for bringing one up. It's not exactly equivalent to what I get but definitely worth looking at.

Comment: @user6144226 I do need all the chunk's items available as there are multiple lookups to be done later (it's not related to the question, though) so lazy materialization will not be of any help.

Comment: @mjwills, added and pushed all three versions. 99.9 microsecond is time of implementation you've suggested

Comment: @ErikPhilips you're right about priorities in general, but there is always a 'but', right? Although you might not understand my needs I'd appreciate if those topics could be discussed elsewhere. I asked for a help of fellow coders, that's all.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Then our comments are worth as much as this quesiton for future readers :)

Answer (score 10):

Not really sure how this stacks up (`ArraySegment`), but give it a try. I've avoided using iterators but not really sure if that is really a gain here.

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> AsChunks<T>(
    this T[] source, int chunkMaxSize)
{
    var chunks = source.Length / chunkMaxSize;
    var leftOver = source.Length % chunkMaxSize;
    var result = new List<T[]>(chunks + 1);
    var offset = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
    {
        result.Add(new ArraySegment<T>(source,
                                       offset, 
                                       chunkMaxSize).ToArray());
        offset += chunkMaxSize;
    }

    if (leftOver > 0)
    {
        result.Add(new ArraySegment<T>(source, 
                                       offset, 
                                       leftOver).ToArray());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Pretty much the same as mine.  30.64 us | 0.1637 us | 0.1531 us.

Comment: more thanks for `ArraySegment`. It looks like I've missed that one completely. It's never late to learn something new :)

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov note that you might consider returning `ArraySegments` directly, without calling `ToArray`. Then no copying happens at all. For many uses cases this is just as good as returning multiple arrays.

Comment: @evk Good point, I should have mentioned that. I wanted to keep the original signature but if you can get away with an `IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>>` the gain is huge.

Comment: @Evk thanks for suggestion, I'll definitely look into that. It'd require some refactoring on the processing side but it does worth checking.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Note that you could refactor to `IEnumerable<IList<T>>`; both `T[]` and `ArraySegment<T>` implement `IList<T>` so you wouldn't be breaking anything.

Comment: Yes, even better to refactor to `IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<T>>`. But definetely better not return `ArraySegment` itself, it even has indexer implemented explicitly, so quite hard to use.

Comment: 72 microseconds for `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` version :(

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov Without `ToArray()`? Of course the downside here is that if you remove `ToArray()` any mutation in a chunk will affect the original array. Not sure if this is an issue in your scenario.

Comment: @Evk I've tested this one - 7 microseconds but very different in use. I need to think it through.

Comment: @InBetween yes, without `ToArray()`. I'm afraid structure implementing an interface adds its cost to such time. Source array in my case is immutable so it's not a problem. I've updated code in GitHub, btw.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov access via interface is adding some cost in this case. If you remove loop over chunk from your test code (replace with something like `sum += chunk.Count`) - it will be faster (faster than array version with the same change). Also it saves memory and reduces garbage collection costs (and memory fragmentation), so also something to consider.

Comment: @Evk Well, that'll make all test cases quicker, won't it? :) If I were to calculate a sum i'd do that another way :) I wanted to include a cost of chunk iteration too as it appears to differ significantly between implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old topic, but it lacks solution using `Memory<T>` and `yield`.
Based on solution using `ArraySegment` we can use

```
public static IEnumerable<Memory<T>> ChunkViaMemory(this T[] source, int size)
{
    var chunks = source.Length / size;
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
    {
        yield return source.AsMemory(i * size, size);
    }
    var leftOver = source.Length % size;
    if (leftOver > 0)
    {
        yield return source.AsMemory(chunks * size, leftOver);
    }
}
```

I run benchmark for array of 50k items chucked into 100 items, for standard Chunk method and compare with `ArraySegment` and `Memory<T>`.

Results shows this approach is much faster then alternatives.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chunk | 1,408.33 us | 22.359 us | 20.914 us | 97.6563 | 412098 B |
| ChunkArraySegment | 113.89 us | 0.750 us | 0.626 us | - | 80 B |
| ChunkMemory | 32.19 us | 0.439 us | 0.411 us | - | 72 B |

Comment: If we are looking for minimum execution time, removal of yield and allocating result array can cut time down to 9.1us but it increases memory allocation on a heap.

Comment: Actually version without `yield` won't allocate much.   
`var result = new Memory<Person>[chunks + leftOver > 0 ? 1 : 0];`
For benchmarks I did it was running from 5 to even 25 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this few lines of code

```
                int chunkSize = 4;
                int skipIndex = 0;
                string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" };
                string[][] chunckResult = new string[words.Length][];

                for (int index = 0; index < words.Length; index++)
                {
                    chunckResult[index] = words.Skip(skipIndex).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();
                    skipIndex += chunkSize;
                    if (skipIndex == words.Length)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Have you tested your code from the performance perspective? What's the time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Code executes with Inclusive rate of 100% and Exclusive rate of 0%

Comment: Execution time is TotalSeconds 0.0002724

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<someObject[]> splitArrayIntoSmallerArrays<someObject>(someObject[] arrayOfSomeObject, int chunkSize)
{
    var output = new List<someObject[]>();
    var newestArray = new List<someObject>();
    for (int i = 0, loopTo = arrayOfSomeObject.Count() - 1; i <= loopTo; i++)
    {

        newestArray.Add(arrayOfSomeObject[i]);
        if (newestArray.Count == chunkSize)
        {
            output.Add(newestArray.ToArray());
            newestArray = new List<someObject>();
        }
    }
    output.Add(newestArray.ToArray());
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this Code:

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/11/16/plinq-and-int32-maxvalue.aspx

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize) {
    if (batchSize <= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchSize));
    }
    using(var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            yield return YieldBatchElements(enumerator, batchSize - 1);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> YieldBatchElements<T>(IEnumerator<T> source, int batchSize) {
    yield return source.Current;
    for (var i = 0; i < batchSize && source.MoveNext(); i++) {
        yield return source.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: 139.5 microseconds. Not as bad as `Group` yet times slower than either of mine.